# MYSQL8 Permanently change password policy requirements

Tags: passwords, policy, mysql-8.0

I am trying to change the password policy requirements in MYSQL8 (Note not MYSQL 5.7). I am using Ubuntu 20.04 server (so no GUI).

I can change them within mysql-8 by using lines such as `SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy=LOW;` and I can see the changes using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';`, however when I restart mysql using `service mysql restart` they return the their default settings.

The Stack Overflow article *36301100* alludes to adding lines to mysqld.cnf file however there is no mysqld.cnf file just the mysql.cnf file under the /etc/mysql/ directory. When I add any lines such as `SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy=LOW;` it causes the mysql server to fail after the `service mysql restart` command.

Another suggestion given is to remove the password plugin with `UNINSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';`, however this strikes me as a bit harsh.

Any suggestions? Thanks, Greg

Answer (score 0):

**Using MYSQL 8**

Navigate to /etc/my.cnf
Add these following lines:

```
 validate_password.policy = LOW
 validate_password.length = 2
 validate_password.mixed_case_count = 0
 validate_password.number_count = 0
 validate_password.special_char_count = 0
```

**Using MYSQL 5.7**
In the /etc/my.cnf file, add this line:

```
validate_password=OFF
```